# videojs with angular and contribAdsSettings error

Tags: angular, video.js

i try to add the ad module to my angular project but i seem to be getting the following error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contribAdsSettings'), i am using the following to initialize the ad module:

```
declare var videojs: any;
import contribAds from 'videojs-contrib-ads';
import ima from 'videojs-ima';

ngAfterViewInit() {

this.player = videojs(this.target.nativeElement, {

  controlBar:{
    captionsButton:{
      order:2
    }
  }

}, () => {

  videojs.registerPlugin('ads', contribAds);
  videojs.registerPlugin('ima', ima);

  this.player.ready(() => {

  // Initialize the ads plugin
  this.player.ads({
    debug: true,
  });

  this.player.ima({
    id: 'VideoPlayer', // Replace with the actual player ID
    adTagUrl: 'https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/vast/tags/inline-linear.xml',
    debug: true,
    
    // Example: Set the player to play a content video after the ad
    adWillPlayMuted: true,
    
    // Example: Customize the ad UI settings
    controls: false, // Hide video controls during ad playback
    disableControlsOnAdBreak: true,
    
    // Example: Set up custom ad display settings
    showControlsForJSAds: false,
    showCountdown: true,
    
    // Example: Configure VAST ad response timeout
    timeout: 8000, // Set the timeout for ad response (milliseconds)
    
  });

  // Request ads to be played as preroll
  this.player.ima.requestAds();

  });
```

when i use import videojs from videojs gives typescript errors so i declare them all to avoid the errors, i am trying to find out what happens but each time get the same result. anyone any idea what is going on?